# Image reflection should not have shadow

Tags: css, image, reflection, shadow

My image has reflection and shadow (by using this css).
The problem is: the shadow should only be on the original image… Now the original image AND the reflection have shadow… (it also reflects the shadow).

[image] (this is not an iPhone screenshot, its just that image on my page)

What should i edit ?

```
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 2px
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.7, transparent), to(white));
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
```

Thx

Evert

ps. Only webkit is okay, it's designed for webkit..

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing your problem; when I move the reflection lower (so the shadow doesn't overlap), the reflection clearly has no shadow.

Comment: This doesn't resolve your problem, but note that `-webkit-gradient` is deprecated. You should use `-webkit-linear-gradient` together with the new gradient syntax.

Comment: @metadept screenshot added in the question.. And.. The reflection is not supposed to be lower…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

1)first one is by wrapping the image in another div and giving the shadow to this div.
like this:

```
<div class="shadow">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

you can apply the shadow right out the .box and give the box-reflect to the .box only.
like this (i added more properties for demonstration purposes only):

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:url(../your_image.xxx) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 2px
   /* DEPRECATED -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.7, transparent), to(white))*/
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%,transparent 70% ,white 100%);
}
.shadow{
    width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
```

you can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tVdA6/1/)

*note that -webkit-gradient is deprecated, you should use -webkit-linear-gradient as suggested by matthias.p

2)Second way is to apply a -webkit-box-mask-image to your reflection, of course if you want to create a .png mask.

```
.box{
/*...other properties here...*/
-webkit-box-reflect: below 2px
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(mask.png) 75 stretch; 
}
```

you can read more about css masks properties [here](https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)